# Работа node.js с mysql

Tags: node.js, denwer, mysql

Приветствую всех)

Изучив немного `node.js`, решил поработать с `MySQL`.

До этого с `MySQL` работал только в `PHP` на денвере. И тут подумалось мне: ведь денвер итак содержит в себе `MySQL` => для простых тестовых выборок совсем не обязательно устанавливать её отдельно. Я прав?

Установил модуль для `MySQL` такой командой: `"npm install mysql"`. Версия ноды 0.8.3.
Набросал простенький примерчик, но нода в очередной раз мне выкинула несколько ошибок.
Код программы и ошибки на скрине:
[image: alt image]

Подскажите, как подружить `node.js` с `MySQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу вашей первой ошибки:

> depreceted: connect() is now done automaticly

Это значит, что после после инициализации подключения, не нужно напрямую вызывать метод `connect`, он вызывается автоматически ( если быть точным - при выполнении первого запроса ), т.е. нужно просто его убрать. К тому-же, они изменили API, но не изменили примера. Теперь вместо `createConnection` нужно использовать `createClient`. В итоге код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var c = mysql.createClient({
   database : 'database name',
   user     : 'user name',
   password : 'user password'
});
c.query('....', function(){
   // ...
})
```

Несмотря на то, что под денвером все будет работать, не стоит бояться установки БД в ручную, зачастую - ничего сложного в этом нет,  в случае mysql - так точно.

По поводу второго модуля:

```
 npm install node-waf -g
```

Это не гарантирует того, что модуль станет, но без этого он не станет точно.

PS: ну и на правах оффтопа - посмотрите в сторону noSQL :)

Comment: Работает!!1 
mysql я раньше устанавливал(ради интереса) но это было давно и не правда)) Просто сейчас нету острой необходимости в отдельной установке, т.к. я пишу(небольшой) скрипт с использованием бд на пхп, и задумываю портировать его на ноду, по этому в данном случае мне легче работать с денвером.

А насчёт второго модуля.. к сожалению он не установился. Жаль, т.к. он заинтересовал меня больше. 

А насчёт noSQL я уже давно подумываю) Но пока хочу по-лучше разобраться в реляционных бд.

Answer (score 1):

Мне показалось, что Вы неверно установили соединение.

На странице [модуля](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) приведен следующий код для установления соединения:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Query result: ', rows);
});

connection.end();
```

Попробуйте его. Однако, я бы Вам рекомендовал использовать вот [этот](http://nodejsdb.org) модуль, поскольку в нем содержится также своеобразный конструктор запросов, а также с его использованием в будущем мигрирование на другую БД может быть выполнено легче.

Comment: Попробовал, одни коды ошибок сменились другими.. http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120730/RnvHAMbb.png  Как я понял из текста ошибки нода не может найти нужный метод.

Так же хотел попробовать тот модуль, что вы посаветовали, но он даже установиться не смог: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120730/Oj4WhUKr.png

Comment: Странно. Сделайте скриншот вот таких строк: 

var mysql = require('mysql'); 

console.log(mysql);



По поводу другого модуля. Я не обратил внимания что у Вас винда, и она на винду не поставится, поскольку он не просто копируется с репозитория, но и собирается у вас на компе при помощи утилиты node-waf. Я вот не в курсе есть ли она под винду.

Comment: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120730/Hl09ngrS.png

Спасибо, что откликнулись, но в общем-то основная задача уже решена благодаря AlexWindHop'у.